# Access - TransferText acExportDelim Exported File Location and Name Not Correct

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem with DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim where it will export the desired file from my query, but it will not format the outputted file name as expected and it places the file one folder up in the selected folder path.

I do the entire export operation via a form. The user selects the folder path in the form, then the query ID, and the VBA code appends them together in the "FileName" parameter of DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim like so:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Export Specification", "QueryName", "Me.FileLocationTextField.Value Me.QueryIDComboBox.Value .csv", TRUE
```

The above code will output the file from the query, but it will have a file name like "Me#FileLocationTextField#Value Me#QueryIDComboBox#Value". The file has the correct contents, it's just that the name is not the text that is stored in the Query ID Combo Box, which is what I would prefer.

The other issue is that the File Location is always one folder up in the folder path. So if the user selects "C:\Users\User\Documents\Exported Files\CSV Files" the file will be exported to "C:\Users\User\Documents\Exported Files".

I've tried setting the confirming the value of Me.FileLocationTextField.Value with a MsgBox and it is indeed showing the correct and full path before it is sent to TransferText acExportDelim. I've also tried several combinations of escape characters and concatenations for the FileName parameter but none have worked to get the file name or the folder path to work correctly.

Comment: Change `"Me.FileLocationTextField.Value Me.QueryIDComboBox.Value .csv"` to `Me.FileLocationTextField.Value & Me.QueryIDComboBox.Value .csv` (remove the quotes and add an ampersand). You may also need to add a backslash in there, too.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! Thank you for the help Kismert! Here is the working code:  `Me.FileLocationTextField.Value &  "\" & Me.QueryIDComboBox.Value ".csv"`